# AutoMapper: How to do something if condition fails?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm mapping an object using AutoMapper and my destination object has already some filled properties at this point.
My Configuration already looks like this:

```
// MapperConfiguration
CreateMap<TestClass, TestClass>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Property1, c => c.Condition((s, d) => string.IsNullOrWithSpace(d.Property1));

// Test Class
class TestClass {
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to write to a log, if the condition fails/the property is already set. Is there a way to achieve this or an alternative workaround?

I'm using AutoMapper v8.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simple solution but it is in a hacking-way style:

```
public static bool IsNullOrWithSpaceWithLog(string x){
  log.Info("something")
  return string.IsNullOrWithSpace(x);
}

CreateMap<TestClass, TestClass>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Property1, c => c.Condition((s, d) => IsNullOrWithSpaceWithLog(d.Property1));
```